# Android Test Orchestrator not working with Android X

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-testing, androidx, androidx-test

I have recently migrated my project to use AndroidX, and have configured test orchestrator for my espresso tests on gradle using the following docs:

https://developer.android.com/training/testing/junit-runner#using-android-test-orchestrator

I have the dependency:

```
androidTestUtil 'androidx.test:orchestrator:1.1.0-beta01'
```

However, none of my tests are executed and looks like they fail when running gradle runs the following adb shell command i.e:

```
adb shell 'CLASSPATH=$(pm path android.support.test.services) app_process / \
  android.support.test.services.shellexecutor.ShellMain am instrument -w -e \
  targetInstrumentation com.example.test/androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner \
  android.support.test.orchestrator/.AndroidTestOrchestrator'
```

from looking at the above: It seems like it is trying to execute this command with android support version as opposed to the androidx version.

It doesn't seem to be documented anywhere what to use for androidx.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Purely by guessing, I changed the following in my gradle config

from:

```
  testOptions {
    execution 'ANDROID_TEST_ORCHESTRATOR'
  }
```

to

```
  testOptions {
    execution 'ANDROIDX_TEST_ORCHESTRATOR'
  }
```

and all seems to work.

Comment: Intuitively obvious to the casual observer. JK -- if I could give you more up arrows I would.

Comment: When switching to ANDROIDX_TEST_ORCHESTRATOR, I am getting `Unknown Execution value 'ANDROIDX_TEST_ORCHESTRATOR'. Possible values are 'host', 'android_test_orchestrator'.`

Comment: I am getting the same exception @MarkHan - did you figure it out?

Comment: Perhaps updating to `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'` fixed it for me. What version are you using? @dazza5000

Comment: When switching to ANDROIDX_TEST_ORCHESTRATOR, I am getting the error `Cannot convert string value 'ANDROIDX_TEST_ORCHESTRATOR' to an enum value of type 'com.android.builder.model.TestOptions$Execution' (valid case insensitive values: HOST, ANDROID_TEST_ORCHESTRATOR)`. Updating `com.android.tools.build:gradle` did not fix that.

Comment: You have to be using Gradle Build Tools 3.2.1 to recognise ANDROIDX_TEST_ORCHESTRATOR

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else struggling with the `Cannot convert string value 'ANDROIDX_TEST_ORCHESTRATOR' to an enum value of type 'com.android.builder.model.TestOptions$Execution' (valid case insensitive values: HOST, ANDROID_TEST_ORCHESTRATOR)` error message, `ANDROIDX_TEST_ORCHESTRATOR` seems to be incompatible with the latest version of IntelliJ (2018.3.5), it worked fine in Android Studio (3.3.2).

Answer (score -1):

Anyone with Complex projects - 
here are my gradle changes

```
repositories {
mavenCentral()
flatDir {
    dirs 'aars'
}
maven {
    url "https://maven.google.com"
}
google()}
```

```
testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
```

```
dependencies {
compile 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0'
compile 'androidx.core:core:1.0.0'
compile 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
compile 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0'
//kapt 'androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler:1.0.0'
androidTestImplementation('androidx.test:runner:1.1.0', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
androidTestImplementation('androidx.test:rules:1.1.0', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
androidTestUtil 'androidx.test:orchestrator:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-idling-resource:3.1.0'
// Espresso support
androidTestImplementation('androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
androidTestImplementation('androidx.test.espresso:espresso-intents:3.1.0', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
androidTestImplementation('androidx.test.espresso:espresso-web:3.1.0', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile('androidx.room:room-runtime:2.0.0', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
})
kapt 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.0.0'
compile('androidx.room:room-rxjava2:2.0.0', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
})
testCompile('androidx.room:room-testing:2.0.0', {
    exclude group: 'com.google.code.gson'
})
androidTestImplementation('androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.1.0') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
}
compile 'androidx.exifinterface:exifinterface:1.0.0'}
```

```
       classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'
```

rest of the errors I had to fix manually but in the end it worked