# What is the equivalent androidTestUtil in a test-only module

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, android-testing

Initially I was using Android Test Orchestrator in my app module. So I had this line in my build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    androidTestUtil "androidx.test:orchestrator...`
    ...
}
```

However I am now moving to a [test-only module](https://developer.android.com/studio/test#use_separate_test_modules_for_instrumented_tests). All of the `androidTestImplementation` keywords become just `implementation`. But what should I do for `androidTestUtil`? Should it become just `util`?

Answer (score 1):

According to Android's [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/junit-runner#using-android-test-orchestrator) it should still be:

> **androidTestUtil** 'androidx.test:orchestrator:x.x.x'

Just make sure you update

```
  testOptions {
    execution 'ANDROID_TEST_ORCHESTRATOR'
  }
```

to

```
  testOptions {
    execution 'ANDROIDX_TEST_ORCHESTRATOR'
  }
```

Credit: [Android Test Orchestrator not working with Android X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52759444/android-test-orchestrator-not-working-with-android-x)

Comment: I don't see where in the documentation you linked to that it mentions androidTestUtil or orchestrator

Comment: Sorry, I linked the wrong android documentation. I just edited my comment with the right link. It shows an example of it being used. https://developer.android.com/training/testing/junit-runner#using-android-test-orchestrator

Comment: Yep so in that link they are showing an app or library module, not a test only module. You can tell because they use `androidTestImplementation`  not `implementation` on the runner. I still don't see how this solution works for test-only modules.

Comment: @tir38 did you end up finding a solution to this?